# How to speed up cloud service running in windows azure?

Tags: azure

I have developed web api and deployed in windows azure. That web api is consumed in android application. That app is slow when fetching data from WEB API.

How to speed up app to fetch data from WEB API?

Thanks.

Comment: you should look at profiling your app first to see where the bottleneck is... is it your webapi operations, is it the connection to your webapi, is it the app, etc...

Comment: I have developed web API

Comment: So much more information is required. Does it perform well on your dev server but not on Azure? What size service are you running? etc.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to figure out why it's slow ?

Is the api method execution slow? Is it calling a database query and the DB is slow? Is it a bandwidth problem between the Android device and their network?

Could be a million and one things without you providing more information but here are a few things you could try.

- Profile your database queries and see that they're executing and returning to the service in a timely fashion
- Call your WebAPI methods from Chrome with the Dev Tools (F12) turned on. Checkout the network tab, and see how long the round trip time is for the request/response compared with the android call
- Find out how many simultaneous calls are hitting your application, it could be that you just need to scale out with more web role processes.